# Matplotlib squishes axis labels when setting labels on twiny() axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to add a second set of tic marks to my plot. I'm getting the original tic marks with `get_xticks()`, converting them to what I want (in this example simply adding 100) and calling `set_xticks()` on an axis I got from `ax.twiny()`.

When I do this, my twin axis labels are all crammed to the right as seen in the top right of the graph.

Here's the code I used:

```
 ax2 = ax.twiny()
 ax2.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()+100)
```

[image]

FYI:

```
 print(ax.get_xticks())
 [  950.  1000.  1050.  1100.  1150.  1200.  1250.]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (incomplete code; needs to be merged with OPs):

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
def shift(x, pos):
    return x+100
formatter = FuncFormatter(shift)

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
```

Read also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772673/matplotlib-imshow-twiny-problems).